# Working of bufferedReader for fetching a file for K-mean clustering

Tags: java, header, statistics, bufferedreader

I have data set with a header and two co-ordinates x and y. I am just curious how bufferedReader works in Java for below code I got from Google for getting Header and data separately in String Variables.

```
File file = new File(fileName);
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String header = bufferedReader.readLine();
        String line = "";
        while(( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null ){
            String[] dataArr = line.split(STR_DELIM);
...
...
...
```

While doing statistics using R we need to right one liner code, where we mention Header = True and it automatically starts reading from line number 2.

But in case of java we are using readLine() function.
But I am not sure how it works.

My main questions are :
1. Until how long readLine() function will read from datasets? Will it look for \n to stop reading?
2. As shown in code, after reading line one using readLine() function, will it start from second line when used in while loop?

Anyone who has worked closely with bufferedReader and its applications, please help me to clarify these doubt.

Thanks---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call to readline() method will return string that ends with '\n' (for unix) or '\r\n' (for windows). 
It will read till the end of stream is reached i.e. until there are lines in the file. I think this answers your 1st question
To answer your second question, every call to readLine() will return successive lines from the input stream (file). It returns null, if there are no more lines.
BufferedReader is same as FileReader with additional buffering capability which is missing in FileReader.
By the way, If you are implementing K-means algorithm I would suggest you take a look at the kmeans() function in MATLAB.
Using MATLAB you could implement kmeans algorithm in less than 5 lines of code. Plus you can use importfile() method in MATLAB to read your input data